# Intersect of two select statements of one table in mysql

Tags: mysql

**IN CLAUSE**

```
SELECT *  FROM build_req WHERE version = "8.2.0.1" IN (SELECT * FROM 
build_req where build_status = "Approval Pending");
```

**ERROR**

Operand should contain 1 column(s)

**UNION**

```
SELECT *  FROM build_req WHERE version = "8.2.0.1" union SELECT * FROM 
build_req where build_status = "Approval Pending";
```

The union is working fine. How do I overcome this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you miss the where condition **and id IN** and `SELECT * FROM` will give all column in where condition you need to only one column

```
SELECT * FROM build_req WHERE version = "8.2.0.1" and build_status = "Approval Pending" ;
```

Comment: i do not know do you have id in table ?

Comment: yep i had . build_id . I tried with that . same error .

Comment: SELECT *  FROM build_req WHERE version = "8.2.0.1"  and build_id = 99 IN (SELECT build_req_id FROM 
build_req where build_status = "Approval Pending")

Comment: have you seen I have write query like this ??

Comment: why do you have  build_id = 99  ?

Comment: it should be like build_id IN only this

Comment: do you have this id in build_req_id in this build_status table ?

Comment: SELECT * FROM build_req WHERE version = "8.2.0.1" and build_id IN (SELECT build_req_id FROM build_req where build_status = "Approval Pending")  **like this?**

Comment: do you have this id in build_req_id in this build_status table ?

Comment: have same table than y r u using sub query ?

Comment: GOT :) THANK YOU